# Parar uma function com jquery?

Tags: jquery

O problema é o seguinte. Eu tenho uma função chamada `auto()` que abre uma div passados 6 segundos quando a página carregar, além disse existe um botão que se for clicado, faz o mesmo. Mas se eu abrir e fechar antes de passar os 6 segundos, a função `auto()` volta a ser executada. Há forma que quando eu carregar no botão, ele cancele a outra função de ser executada?

O meu código é o seguinte

```
function abre(){
    auto
    $("#noti").css("display", "block");
    $("#noti").animate({
        width: "100px"
    }, 500, function(){
       $("#noti").animate({
        height: "200px" 
    });
    });
    $(".left_noti2").animate({
        left: "100px"
    }, 500);
    $("#chevron").hide(0);
    $("#chevron2").show(0);
}
function fecha(){
    $("#noti").css("display", "block");
    $("#noti").animate({
        height: "50px"
    }, 500, function(){
        $("#noti").animate({
            width: "0px"
        })
    });
    $(".left_noti2").delay(500).animate({
        left: "0px"
    }, 500);
    $("#chevron2").hide(0);
    $("#chevron").show(0);
}

//Função que abre automaticamente
function auto(){
  setTimeout(function(){
      abre();
  }, 3000);
}


//chama as funções ao carregar nas divs
$("#abrir").click(abre);

$("#fecha").click(fecha);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O setTimeout quando invocado retorna um ponteiro para o poder interromper. Assim se chamares o `clearTimeout` com esse ponteiro como argumento interrompes o `setTimeout`. Um exemplo seria:

```js
var espera = null;

function abre() {
  clearTimeout(espera);
  /// etc...
}

function fecha() {
  //...
}

//Função que abre automaticamente
var espera = setTimeout(abre, 3000);

//chama as funções ao carregar nas divs
$("#abrir").click(abre);
$("#fecha").click(fecha);
```

Comment: Obrigado! Resultou perfeitamente, irei dar a resposta como aceite mal puder